# Changing element order in gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

In my application I have a gridview containing some items.
I am looking a way change those elements order.
By default, gridview orders my items in this way (starts filling top row):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGYhx.png

What I am seeking is that items would fill left column first:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwQIc.png

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to arrange your items like that in the adapter you pass to the GridView.  In the adapter's `getView()`, you can translate the position in the GridView and have it return the correct view for that position, according to the rules you have specified in your screens.